# Trying to instal a new stencil js component I get this error?

Tags: node.js, stenciljs

I'm trying to get started with my first stencil.js component but have hit a snag.

I CD into the folder hit

```
npm init stencil
```

get the stencil prompt and select component then.

> [terminal Error: reaf ECONNRESET......](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU44i.png)

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but alternatively you can use the component starter repo directly: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-component-starter

Comment: sounds like your terminal has no internet connection, or npm has some issues with their servers ‍♂️ you could check the npm status page for any incidents.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below through command line

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

and run `npm init stencil`
setting NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 wokrs for me,

after this if you get `EBUSY: resource busy or locked` error then do `npm cache clean`
and then run `npm init stencil`